# jquery and bootstrap navbar does not working in layout for collapsing or expanding submenu in angular 7

Tags: jquery, angular, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a big problem with using bootstrap navbar for collapse and expand the sub menu in layout in angular 7

I create two layouts for my website, a layout for dashboard and another for login section.
I use a bootstrap template for dashboard.for implementing using two layout in my project, I created component per my section (a component for dashboard and another for login) with layout.routing and layout.module file for handling all layout page in project like the below image:
[image: the structure of my layout file in my project]

in this scenario when I see my dashboard, all the sub menu is expanded and the **href="#"** in the **a tag** had routing behavior instead of collapse sub menu.
see the second image, please.

[image: the output result in chrome]

When I paste my dashboard html code into app.component.html, that's work and when the page is load, the sub menu is collapse and when I click on the fa-arrow icon the icon worked and the sub menu expanded.like the below image

[image: when the page comes up]

and then

[image: when I click the arrow icon to expand and show the sub menu]

here, this my dashboardLayoutComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-dashboard-layout',
templateUrl: './dashboard-layout.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./dashboard-layout.component.css']
})
export class DashboardLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() { }
}
```

and this screenshot is for layout.routing.module

[image: LayoutRoutingModule]
What should I do to solve this problem.
please advise and say your recommendations to me.
thanks.

Comment: FYI is not good practice to use Jquery and Angular together

Comment: use ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap or md-bootstrap to get a non-jQuery navigation fit for Angular

Comment: I tried to using ng-bootstarp instead of bootstrap but it doesn't work. AkberIqbal

Comment: What does your mean about FYI?? Explain please. @PatricioVargas

Comment: For Your Information

Comment: what do you mean in doesn't work ? what error you got>?

Comment: in the picture, when I put the html code into DashboardLayout the arrow icon doesn't work and the menu is expanded and the arrow icon doesn't collapse sub menu.@PatricioVargas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with using Lazy Loading in Agular.
after all I tried all solution to solve my problem, at the end I found a lazy loading approach in angular and used that.
if we created at least two module for each section in project and config all components module in the layout module of that parent component, we can use the Bootstrap, Jquery and angular with together.
like the code below:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardLayoutComponent } from './dashboard-layout/dashboard-layout.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('../login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('../login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('../adminDashboard/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'get-all-product',
        loadChildren: () => import('../adminDashboard/get-all-products/get-all-product.module').then(m => m.GetAllProductModule)
      },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class LayoutRoutingModule { }
```

In this code we have two section, first the login layout and the second is the dashbaordLayout.